# Syslog UDP logger for nest.js

Tags: logging, nestjs, syslog, winston

Researching the various packages that are available, I cannot seem to find a logger that allows for syslog logging over UDP for nest.js.

In the node.js world this could be accomplished with a combination of winston and winston-syslogudp.

Is there anything available? Or is there an approach that needs to be followed?